# What about non calculus programming?

Tags: computer-science

I recently asked about [new languages and language features of the last 10 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549274/what-programming-languages-and-language-features-are-under-10), but apparently there is none.

However I noticed one issue is that most of our focus is on calculus of various types. But thinking about it, theoretically I can see Neural Networks and Genetic Programming as non calculus based models for programming, that although lack stand alone implementations, are interesting ideas born in recent years (say less than lambda 1930).

Also equally out-of-the-box are query languages, regex and graph/tree based designs, that although mathematical in part, are not calculus, which got me thinking about what other non calculus designs in programming are important now, and what other fields might provide us with new programming paradigms?

**Note: ** this question is not about "new", but about not originating from calculus.

Comment: I'm not sure this constitutes as an answer, but Parallel Processing is very new and could (possibly-maybe) evolve into a new programming paradigm.

Comment: Well it's not new but I'm not asking about new this time, so it's a valid answer. Should probably put it there instead of as a comment :)

Comment: NN and Genetic Programming interesting new ideas born in recent years? They have been around for ages.

Comment: I find this question a bit weird. First, Neural Networks are heavily based on Math and calculus. Second, it's obvious that there is a lot in programming that has nothing to with calculus: OO, Design Patterns, testing, etc.

Comment: Reading the question again, don't you mean 'genetic' programming instead of 'generic' programming?

Comment: NN are not based on calculus, calculus can be used to describe them but that's it. Anyways OO and Testing is indeed a good answer. Design Patterns on the other hand are are a meta result of programming

Comment: @eljenso indeed, thanks for pointing it out fixed it.

Comment: As for new they're relatively new compared to other things, even the biological models are quite new compared to calculus.

Comment: I don't understand where the existing languages "came from calculus". Larry Wall used calculus to write Perl? I don't think so. You might be able to use calculus to discuss Perl internals but that doesn't make it derived from calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think any major shifts in these areas will probably come about through shifts in how we think about the problems rather than the languages we use to solve them.

The tools we have now are rather good at solving computational problems as they are currently framed. New views of the problems will certainly drive the creation of new languages, but that is a by-product rather than the impetus.

Comment: Exactly, that's what interests me.New sources to look at for solving problems, not languages.

Answer (score 3):

Neural networks are more than 50 years old, see e.g. the  [Perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron).

[Genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) is more than 40 years old.

Now the original question got edited, so age is no longer relevant ...

BTW, object-oriented programming originated in simulation, more than 40 years ago (Simula 67).

Most other programming languages are either derived bottom-up from what a machine can do (imperative languages starting with FORTRAN in 1954) or from some mathematical notion of computation (e.g. lambda calculus inspired Lisp in 1957 and later other functional languages. Prolog is another example derived from mathematical logic). The relation of programming languages to calculus that you see is mostly accidental, because numerical computations were the major use of computers in the early days and are still important today.

Comment: I'm sure the OP meant 'genetic' programming, but the conclusion stays the same.

Comment: Well that still is fairly new. Compared to other models of programming.

Comment: Anyways new isn't relevant to this question. It's the non mathematical background

Answer (score 2):

New programming paradigms could come about for Parallel Programming practices.  Currently, there are many ways of handling programs running on multiple processors, some good, some bad.  I expect that with more research in the subject, several core methods will become commonplace for new languages to incorporate so they can be used in an "easy" way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that lexical programming is going to come to the forefront more and more as we get closer to AI that interfaces with people.

Answer (score 1):

Calculus isn't math, it's just part of math-- as a whole, all programming languages are mathematically-based, and programs can be turned into algebraic structures (or, more theoretically, into lambda calculus or a turing machine construct). What I'm trying to say is that all work on the computer-science aspect of programming (as tagged) is bound to be based in mathematics, though perhaps not calculus, so the question as such isn't fair. The stuff that isn't is stuff like Knuth's Literate Programming, which focuses on the non-mathematical sides of programming-- documentation, etc., and it's not really new.

Edit: The original question has since been updated. Thanks, I suppose.

Comment: New is irrelevant, and math is fair play because most anything can be modeled through math, however I mean non calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Non calculus programming sounds to me by definition as a composition of something physical into a whole entity, which should result into another entity as a whole through computation performed by non human created physics or/and device. We can think,it's definitely a future of calculations, because it would be something originated beyond human comprehension boundaries. There should be employed something which works but we do not understand how. 
     But, in the other way of thinking, it is not the future. It is how the universe is made, including us as a whole. So, it is not very practical, having in mind our brain. Obviously, we can try to employ something, as quantum calculations, quantum entanglement or other physical phenomenon which we did not discover yet. And it is pretty much it, what an option we have. It is not very practical so far, to try employ something, which is we are made of.